# pyautogui cannot write the @ symbol

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've been trying to produce the "@" character with pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite("@")
pyautogui.typewrite("\x40")
```

But I can't seem to make it type a "@" in any way.

My keyboard uses <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to create an "@" symbol, but I haven't been able to make that work either.

Comment: What operating system and version of Python are you using? I'm able to type out the @ symbol on my machine.

Answer (score 7):

I did not find a way to do it with the `write` method, but in some scenarios you could work around it by putting the `@` on the clipboard and paste it:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('@')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pyautogui.hotkey('altright','2')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Although manually I would press AltGr+2 to get "@", this code doesn't produce anything (Belgian keyboard layout).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try to change keyboard layout:
$ setxkbmap us

Comment: Please clarify how I should use this command?

Comment: run this command in ubuntu terminal, it will change keyboard layout

Comment: Works like a charm for autopy (very much appreciated), doesn't seem to work for pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

use the hotkey function

```py
from pyautogui import hotkey
hotkey("alt","l")
```

This is what works for me on mac, you will know your windows shortcut to write an @ symbol... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the suggested solutions work for keyboard layouts that isn't the standard US keyboard layout. The problem is that pyautogui doesn't really handle different keyboard layouts that well. Switching to standard US keyboard layout in your OS should solve any issues with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I've came upon the same problem, after some experimentation and checking [pyautogui's documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html?highlight=type#keyboard-keys), I've come up with the following solution, using alt codes:

```
pyautogui.pyautogui.hotkey('alt','num6','num4')
```

This should succesfully write out '@'